# After deleting Gradle's build cache and building, some tasks are still marked as FROM-CACHE

Tags: gradle, caching, incremental-build

I start off by deleting Gradle's build cache

`$ rm -rf $GRADLE_HOME/caches/build-cache-*`

I manually confirm this directory is gone. I also clean to ensure nothing from incremental build will interfere

`$ ./gradlew clean`

I then run a build w/ build-cache enabled:

```
$ ./gradlew --build-cache --scan app:assembleDebug
...
238 actionable tasks: 172 executed, 49 from cache, 17 up-to-date
```

Checking the generated report I see that some tasks are still marked as FROM-CACHE. How is this happening?

[image]

FWIW I'm using Gradle 5.6.3. I also don't use a remote build cache.

---

UPDATE: after clearing build cache, here's what's left in the cache dir:

```
$ pwd
/Users/jasonatwood/.gradle/caches

$ ls -al
total 24
drwx------  11 jasonatwood  staff   352 Dec 13 18:11 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 jasonatwood  staff   288 Oct 15 17:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 jasonatwood  staff   448 Oct 29 16:07 5.4.1
drwxr-xr-x  15 jasonatwood  staff   480 Nov 26 18:25 5.6.3
drwxr-xr-x  35 jasonatwood  staff  1120 Dec 11 14:14 jars-3
drwxr-xr-x   5 jasonatwood  staff   160 Oct 15 17:44 journal-1
drwxr-xr-x   7 jasonatwood  staff   224 Oct 15 17:50 modules-2
drwxr-xr-x   5 jasonatwood  staff   160 Oct 15 17:50 transforms-2
-rw-r--r--   1 jasonatwood  staff    39 Oct 15 17:27 transforms-2.lock
-rw-------   1 jasonatwood  staff    28 Oct 22 16:34 user-id.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 jasonatwood  staff    17 Dec 13 18:00 user-id.txt.lock
```

If I understand correctly, I don't need to delete any of these.

Answer (score 1):

The local task cache in the `.gradle` directory within the root project might interfere.

In order to disable the local/global caching altogether, use `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.caching=false
```

Comment: Thanks. I do want to use caching though. I'm  trying to learn what gets put into the build cache so I want to know how to fully clear it first.

Comment: @tir38 with a custom `clean` task one can delete whatever one wants - but unless disabling caching altogether, you'd likely also have to delete the downloads (not sure if this counts as a cache-able task)... and I'd wonder, if not these `.lock` files are markers for completed/cached tasks.

Comment: I re-read your answer. I'm now curious about the .gradle directory in the root project directory. What gets cached there? I can't find anything in the docs. I thought the in-project cache was all within /build directories within each module directory

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the local build cache and don't use a remove cache, Gradle should indeed not be able to fetch anything cached on the next build. However, I don't think you actually removed anything.

The `GRADLE_HOME` environment variable, if you have it, should points to an unpacked local Gradle distribution. It could be something like `/Users/jasonatwood/gradle-6.0-all`. It would be wrong to set it to a path that is not a Gradle distribution.

The Gradle build cache resides in `/Users/jasonatwood/.gradle/caches/build-cache-1`.

When you try to remove it with `$ rm -rf $GRADLE_HOME/caches/build-cache-*`, you are using `GRADLE_HOME` as if it is pointing to the root of your home folder (`/Users/jasonatwood`), which it most likely isn't.

So instead, use this for removing it: `$ rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/build-cache-*`

Or, at the very least, verify that the cache folder has indeed been removed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the env var set right: `echo $GRADLE_HOME
/Users/jasonatwood/.gradle`. All of my `gradle-x.x-all` directories are in `/Users/jasonatwood/.gradle/wrapper/dists`All of the tools that I use that depend on GRADLE_HOME are behaving correctly so I don't think I have that set incorrectly.

Comment: I updated my initial question w/ contents of cache dir after clearing build cache

Answer (score 0):

If I run a `--scan` and look at the FROM-CACHE tasks in the generated HTML report.
I then look at the build cache keys for those FROM-CACHE tasks. I then go find those keys on my local machine. I see they are generated at the same time as the rest of the build. So I'm guessing that Gradle is using build cache *within* a build and not just across builds.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a need to invalidate cache every time you restart the IDEA. This may be due to shared indexes reuse. What I did Settings --> Tools --> Shared Indexes -> Download Automatically and it resolved all the pain.

Earlier the setting was Don't download use Local.